# Microsoft - Print to PDF makes text unselectable

Tags: html, css, windows, pdf, printing

When a website visitor uses their computer's "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer (or some other PDF printer on their computer) to print content from a website, the text of the resulting pdf is not selectable, almost as if it is a scanned image, not printed text. I came across this issue when a user of a website I managed asked about this. We had recently launched a new site and this behavior became apparent to the user. However, as I dig into it further, it doesn't appear to be specifically related to our site as I was just able to repeat it using Chrome and Microsoft's Print to PDF function. Is this pdf printer issue, CSS issue or something else?

[Sample pdf (Windows 10, Chrome, Microsoft Print to PDF)](https://1drv.ms/b/s!Aqennc4CDrFViOgqvHDLEXmz95_fTw?e=awVViR)

Comment: Maybe there is an invisible overlay that keeps you from selecting the text. Do you use such overlays on your sites?

Comment: I thought about that and tried removing all the CSS code I could via Chrome and Firefox's debugging tools. Didn't change anything. Beside, I am noticing the behavior on other sites. See my sample pdf from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

Proven solution: instead of choosing 'print to pdf', use 'save as pdf' from the drop-down list after right-clicking 'print' on the web page

Comment: What if you only have access to the PDF file already created ? There is anyway of making it selectable ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem with the CSS - this is a [known bug](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-print-to-pdf-makes-text-unselectable-in/4c1b570b-2362-48f0-b1fb-007705a2aa37) in Microsoft's Print to PDF feature.

As of right now it is recommended that you use some other tool, such as Adobe Reader which tends to work better than Edge or other PDF readers and has a print function explained in tutorial.

**Additional Material**:

- [Microsoft Print to PDF makes text unselectable in Vector PDF and Hyperlinks unclickable.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/print-to-pdf-generating-bloated-but-unsearchable/15e32194-7bc6-4f57-ad38-abc0b2089e94)
- [Print to PDF generating bloated but unsearchable PDF files](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/print-to-pdf-generating-bloated-but-unsearchable/15e32194-7bc6-4f57-ad38-abc0b2089e94)

Comment: Thanks.  Would this bug impact other pdf printers on the same system? Like the adobe pdf printer or cutePDF?

Comment: @daveheckler It would not. As I said in the answer, Adobe Reader should be OK.